# How do I use the IN SQL operator when I have a set of values to check for of which any match will suffice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the following query where both tables consist of one integer column:

```
INSERT INTO otherNumbers(number)
VALUES(
    CASE
        WHEN (2202 in (select * from numbers)) THEN 2
        WHEN (2201 in (select * from numbers)) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
);
```

I am preparing the above SQL query for a MySQL server instance and as part of that query I want to check if a certain value is contained within a set. I have achieved that with the following syntax:

`2202 IN (SELECT * FROM numbers)`

However, I also have a case where any match of a set of values suffices. In pseudo-SQL, I'd like to do something like this: `(2202, 2203, 2204) ANY IN (SELECT * FROM numbers)` which obviously will not work.

Due to the nature of the data, I want to avoid a logic explosion in the form of:

`2202 IN (SELECT * FROM numbers) OR 2203 IN (SELECT * FROM numbers) OR 2204 IN (SELECT * FROM numbers)`

Since the terminology regarding my question is pretty general (the keyword is `IN`), I could not find any questions describing my problem, even though I believe there to be.

What is the best practice way of achieving my desired result? One approach I can think of using an inner join on both sets and see if the rows returned are bigger than 0, but I can't think of a way to express this.

Comment: Are you looking for the reverse? `SELECT * FROM NUMBERS WHERE MYCOLUMN IN (2202,2203,2204)` ?

Comment: your question is not clear to me  .. please update  your question add  a proper data sample and the expecet result

Comment: Please show the full query.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the full original query. The tables designs are not included, as they are just a single column consisting of integers.

Comment: Please share the table structure and some sample data.

Comment: @NicoHaase That's doesn't seem necessary anymore as others have grasped the problem pretty clearly. To create the table: `CREATE TABLE numbers (number INT);` and the other table is exactly the same, with a different name (someNumbers). You can fill in any integers you want there to get some sample data. I don't think it matters for this question.

Answer (score 1):

A In clause can be refactored  as an inner join

```
select  * 
from ( 
  select  2202 my_num
  UNION 
  select  2203 
  UNION 
  select  2204
) t1  
INNER JOIN  (
  select my_col 
  from my_table 
) t2 on t1.my_num = t2.my_col
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use `FIND_IN_SET` and a variable ?

Something like:

```
SET @user_ids = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) FROM `user` WHERE `user_type` = 'administrator');
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`id`, @user_ids);
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table with all the values you need (2202, 2203, 2204, ...). Join to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * as n FROM numbers HAVING n IN (2202, 2203, 2204))
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How could this snippet insert 2, 1, or 0 into a new table?

Comment: It can't, this answers the original question of finding an intersection of two lists. There was originally no mention of mapping the values. Mapping the values requires either repetitive code or a table to provide that mapping. The question is horribly written.

Comment: Thanks in advance to avoid uncommented answer. The solution and only that rarely explain itself for others that don't know the context.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists` conditions, like so:

```
insert into othernumbers(number)
values(
    case
        when exists (
            select 1
            from numbers
            where num in (2202, 2203, 2204)
        ) then 2
        when exists (
            select 1
            from numbers
            where num = 2201
        ) then 1
        else 0
    end
);
```